# Sencha Open Tooling and Docker

Tags: extjs, dockerfile

I am attempting to setup CI/CD for a frontend project using Docker, ExtJS and open tooling. Because of the odd authentication process, I am unable to use npm to build a production version of the app. It appears that the build process keeps checking in with the sencha repo. You can overcome this with most git repos by generating a token and including that in the docker file. Question is: is it possible to do the same with the sencha npm repo?

Comment: Nevermind, I found something.

Comment: Please share the answer - maybe this will help those who face a similar problem